# Pandas set index or reindex without changing the order of the data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have a dataframe I sorted so the index is not in order so I want to reorder the index so that sorted values have an index that is sequential I have not been able to figure this out should I remove the index or is there a way to set the index? When I reindex it should sorts by the index which unsorts by index.

Comment: `df=df.reset_index(drop=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

I made some dummy data to show this. I hope this answers your question. Leave comments if you have any questions.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3], 'y': [120, 8, 32]})
df = df.reset_index(drop=False).rename(columns={'index': 'ID'})
df = df.sort_values(by='y', ascending=True)
# After Sorting
print(df)
print("-----------------------")
# After Recovering
print(df.reindex(df.ID.to_list()).drop(columns='ID'))
```

**Output**:

```
   ID  x    y
1   1  2    8
2   2  3   32
0   0  1  120
-----------------------
   x    y
1  2    8
2  3   32
0  1  120
```

Comment: @bryan Please check the answer and leave comments if you have any question. I hope this helps.

Comment: he only needed `reset_index(drop=True) ` see his answer

Comment: @ansev Yeah. I re-read his question. It's a vanilla `df.reset_index(drop=True)`. Either I will change this answer or delete it (more likely), as your comment itself answers it.

Answer (score -1):

df=df.reset_index(drop=True)? – ansev 1 min ago

Comment: Why did you copy the comment into an answer?

Comment: @rafaelc I was trying to ansev answered the question but It wouldn't let me let him answer it.